# Clarification required on Spring Boot validator

Tags: spring-boot, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Folks, I have a project in SpringBoot 3.2.2 and am trying to add validators (`@NotEmpty`) to the input - but, it doesn't seem to work. Here are the things that I have already done / tried.

1. Added the following dependency

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Note: I also tried with hibernate-validator dependency as well - but, no luck there as well

2. I added `@Validated` annotation to my controller + `@Valid` annotation to the parameter - highlighted below in the code

   ```
   @RestController
   @Validated
   @RequestMapping("/api/posts")
   public class PostController {
       private PostService postService;

       public PostController(PostService postService) {
           this.postService = postService;
       }

       @PostMapping
       public ResponseEntity<PostDto> createPost (@Valid @RequestBody PostDto postDto) {       
           return new ResponseEntity<>(postService.createPost(postDto), HttpStatus.CREATED);
       }
   ```
3. In my DTO class, I added the `@NotEmpty` annotation - importing the **jakarta**.validation.constraints. I read that the `javax.validation.constraints` doesn't work for SpringBoot projects greater than 3.x version.

   ```
   import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
   public class PostDto {
       private Long id;

       @NotEmpty (message = "Title cannot be empty")
       private String title;
   ```

I also tried with hibernate-validator dependency as well - but, no luck there as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Validator annotation is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77513554/spring-validator-annotation-is-not-working)

Comment: I think I found the solution. I had to use the following dependency instead of spring-boot-starter-validation
        <dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
 </dependency>